# I Keep Getting this Error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 12

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, int, indexoutofboundsexception

My program basically takes a list of ISBN numbers and determines if they're valid or not. So the error is at: s1[l]=digits[i][l-1]+digits[i][l]; This line of code takes the partial sum of the ISBN numbers using the for-loop. The other loop below it takes the partial sum of all the ints in the array s1. Help please? The error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 12
at ISBN.main(ISBN.java:67)

  import java.util.*;
  import java.io.*;

  public class ISBN {
  public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException{
//Reads file line by line
  File ISBNFile = new File ( "isbn_input.txt" );
  Scanner input = new Scanner(ISBNFile);
  String [] preISBN = new String [9999];
  int i = 0;
  int j =0;
  int l =0;
  int m = 0;
  int count =0;
  while (input.hasNextLine()){
    String line = input.nextLine();
    preISBN [i] = line;
    i++;
    count++;
                             }
    input.close();

    //Makes new array with specified count
    String [] ISBN = new String [count];
    String [] ISBNresult = new String [count];
 for(i=0;i<ISBN.length;i++){
   ISBN [i] = preISBN [i];
                           }
// int [] s1 = new int =
 int [] [] digits = new int [ISBN.length] [12];
 int [] s1 = new int [12];
 int [] s2 = new int [12];
 //Loads digits [] [] with values that will later be summed
 for(i=0;i<ISBN.length;i++){
   if(ISBN[i].length()!=12){
     ISBNresult [i] = "Invalid";
     continue;       
   }

   for(j=0;j<12;j++){

      if(ISBN[i].charAt(j)=='X'||ISBN[i].charAt(j)=='x'){
        digits [i] [j] = 10;
      }
      else if(ISBN[i].charAt(j)=='-'){
        digits [i] [j] = 0;
      } 
      else   
      if(ISBN[i].charAt(j)==1||ISBN[i].charAt(j)==2||ISBN[i].charAt(j)==3||ISBN[i].charAt(j)==4||ISBN[i].charAt(j)==5||ISBN[i].charAt(j)==6||ISBN[i].charAt(j)==7||ISBN[i].charAt(j)==8||ISBN[i].charAt(j)==9){                                                     
      digits [i][j] = Character.getNumericValue(ISBN[i].charAt(j)); 
      }
      else{
      ISBNresult[i] = "Invalid";
      break;
      }
                    }


 }
 for(i=0;i<ISBN.length;i++){
   for(j=0;j<ISBN[i].length();j++){
     if(ISBN[i].length()!=12){
       ISBNresult [i] = "Invalid";
       continue;         
     }
     s1[0]=digits[i][0];
     for(l=1;l<=12;l++){
     s1[l]=digits[i][l-1]+digits[i][l];
     }

     s2[0]=s1[0];
     for(m=1;m<=12;m++){
     s2[m]=s2[m-1]+s1[m];    
     }
   }
   if(s2[12]%11==0){
     ISBNresult[i]="Valid";   
   }
   else{
     ISBNresult[i]="Invalid";
   }
 }

      File outFile = new File("isbn_output.txt");
      FileWriter fWriter = new FileWriter (outFile, true);
      PrintWriter pWriter = new PrintWriter (fWriter);
      for(i = 0;i<ISBN.length;i++){
  pWriter.println (ISBN[i]+ " "+ ISBNresult[i] );

  }
  pWriter.close();
       }
      }
```

Comment: You should refactor your code. Try to create class which will be responsible for parsing the file and add there few small methods. Also try to use lists/collections instead of arrays as Sayem Ahmed wrote.

Answer (score 5):

you have declared s1 as

```
 int [] s1 = new int [12];
```

it will have 12 elements but index is from 0 to 11.

in the following code

```
   for(l=1;l<=12;l++){
     s1[l]=digits[i][l-1]+digits[i][l];
     }
```

when l = 12, you are equating the result to s[12].

but there is no s[12], (max is s[11])hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(l=1;l<=12;l++){
    s1[l]=digits[i][l-1]+digits[i][l];
}
```

`l` becomes `12` at the last iteration, effectively making the second part of the addition statement like this.

```
digits[i][12]
```

Same case is with `s1[l]` too, which becomes `s1[12]`, as both are declared like this

```
int [] [] digits = new int [ISBN.length] [12];
int [] s1 = new int [12];
```

Always remember that the maximum accessible index of an array is `array.length-1`. Hence, for an array of length `12`, the last index will be `11`.

Answer (score 0):

The array is defined as 12.

```
int [] [] digits = new int [ISBN.length] [12];

s1[0]=digits[i][0];
for(l=1;l<=12;l++){
    s1[l]=digits[i][l-1]+digits[i][l];
}
```

You exceeded at [l] where l == 12.

[l] starts at 0 until 11.

Answer (score 0):

This all is happening because you are assigning value to the `12th` index of array `s1` and `s2`. Also you are not breaking the loop when `ISBN[i].length >= 12`.
Your for loop should be like this:

```
 for(i=0;i<ISBN.length;i++){
   for(j=0;j<ISBN[i].length();j++){
     if(ISBN[i].length()<=12){
       ISBNresult [i] = "Invalid";
       continue;         
     }
     else if (ISBN[i].length() > 12)
     {
         break;
     }

     s1[0]=digits[i][0];
     for(l=1;l<=12;l++){
     s1[l]=digits[i][l-1]+digits[i][l];
     }

     s2[0]=s1[0];
     for(m=1;m<12;m++){
     s2[m]=s2[m-1]+s1[m];    
     }
   }
   if(s2[11]%11==0){
     ISBNresult[i]="Valid";   
   }
   else{
     ISBNresult[i]="Invalid";
   }
 }
```